# Changing size of image in Pygame

Tags: python, image, pygame, resize, surface

I'm creating a Pygame sprite. I need to change its size as the PNG file I've loaded is too big. The dimensions are currently 356x354. I need them to be 35x35

I've loaded the image using this code and declared the variable as `img`.

```
img=pygame.image.load("C:\\Pikachu_Sprite.png")
```

I've then tried to use this code to resize "img"

```
pygame.transform.scale(img,(35,35))
```

But it doesn't do anything.

In addition to this I've got an error in the terminal saying
`libpng warning: Interlace handling should be turned on when using png_read_image`.

I don't understand what this is but I suspect it relates to my problem of not being able to resize the image/surface.

Comment: Is the only issue the fact that you didn't actually save the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign `pygame.transform.scale(img,(35,35))` to a variable otherwise it won't be saved.

Also, the error message is a bug in an old version of pygame, try updating pygame by using `python3 -m pip install -U pygame` or if that doesn't work, try `python -m pip install Pygame>=2.0.0.dev6`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.

```
img = pygame.transform.scale(img, (35, 35))
```