# Can I change the size of an image in PyGame

Tags: python, pygame

Is there a way in PyGame where when you blit an image, you can change the size of it? It would be helpful for making certain games. Any help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing size of image in Pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59812053/changing-size-of-image-in-pygame)

Answer (score -1):

Use pygame.transform.scale:

```
image = pygame.image.load(filename)
image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (x, y))
screen.blit(image)
```